# datagridview unselect event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

How do I detect unselect event of a datagridview( ie focus lost)?

I did search for a bit and couldn't find on web.

Thanks guys.

Comment: just in case someone else is looking for similar solution, you can unselect(deselect) using datagridview.ClearSelection()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use

`Leave` Event which Occurs when the input focus leaves the DataGridView

`CellLeave` Event which Occurs when a cell loses input focus and is no longer the current cell

`RowLeave` Event which Occurs when a row loses input focus and is no longer the current row